# Downloading a list of Riemann hypothesis critical strip zeros

Tags: riemann-zeta

Can one download a big list of numbers that result in zeros on the critical strip?

Comment: What is big ? What for ? http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/zeta_tables/

Comment: @user1952009 that would do it I guess, there are 10 trillion zero's and I doubted someone has compiled a 10 trillion list so "big" was my only option. Thanks so much

Comment: What for ? In Mathematica and many other math programs there is `ZetaZero[k]`

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but in this question I outlined how to download the first 5mln (or more) non-trivial zeros. Note that the website I refer to could have changed in the mean time and maybe better download options have become available. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226074/how-could-i-get-access-to-more-than-the-first-2-mln-non-trivial-zeros-of-zeta